# some fonts are bold and some not

Tags: html, css, fonts, rendering, arabic

I'm having problem to find why fonts are bold, even tho i didnt apply bold, but half are not bold. which is kind of more confusing.

so some are bold and some are not.

[**Warning, link plays arabic vocals !**] :)

check following screenshot and here is [live demo](http://v3.globalquran.com/#!/quran-wordbyword%7Cen.sahih/1) link (on demo link will play audio, please click on pause and it wont play again on refresh)

[image]

if you see on top right corner, that arabic word is showing normal and next to it the other arabic fonts are bold.

on second line, same second word is not bold, which it was on first line. o.0

Comment: Seems to be a browser issue - the two words look the same to me on the live demo.

Comment: Can you disable the sound on your demo or at least warn us before we click the link?

Comment: @Sparky672 you can pause the audio and it wont play again on refresh

Comment: @PaulTomblin ya you are right, its browser issue, how can we fix it? but same font on same browser, but on other site works fine!

Comment: that's after it has played unexpectantly.  Please remove it from your demo.  Would you want church bells on my answer? (I want neither).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant ok added warning message on top, next to link. i hope that helps.

Comment: Am I right that, in your screenshot, the words that start with alif are all bolded, and the words that *aren't* bolded don't contain alif? So, uh, maybe this "KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh" font really likes the letter alif, and is trying to upvote all the words that contain it? :-P

Comment: Yes, thank-you.  I was on an important telephone call when I went to read this question and the unexpected sound was a very loud interruption.

Comment: I added a much clear warning.  I really don't mind the content, it just needed a clearer warning for those in offices, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility (that I have experienced) is that the font-face you are using does not have bold for the things you are looking for. (btw, I can't tell differences in my browser, Opera, everything looks gray).

I experienced this with a font I implemented using @font-face and font that the font I had chosen didn't have any bold versions at all for  to use.

Comment: thanks.. i think its defo the font issue. i will use some other font now, i think that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems be an artifact of how the text is rendered.

If you take the text value of one word in your span and move it to another, it renders the exact same way.  In other words, this isn't caused by CSS.  Different text seems to render at different weight.

Comment: this works fine on other sites.. here is example: http://allahsquran.com/learn/  on top click on [W] icon to see word by word texts.. you will see, all text are fine and same weight